# Kivy App After building with buildozer is not running

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I have linked log files created while building with buildozer. Please Help Me.[My Source Code And Apk file with log files](https://github.com/Susansujakhu/app.git)
attached

Comment: If you can connect your phone to your computer, try running `buildozer -v android debug deploy run logcat` to see the logcat output. That may contain a clue as to what is happening.

Comment: i tried it but cant find solution.. i have attached all required files check if you can solve it. and thanks for support @JohnAnderson

Comment: I don't see any logcat output.